Unable to get public no-arg constructor for ChangeLogParser of Liquibase
Using maven, i have liquibase-core dependency in my pom.xml:
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.27.0</version>
 </dependency>

When I execute
CommandScope updateCommand = new CommandScope("update")
                    .addArgumentValue("driver", String.valueOf(map.get("driver")))
                    .addArgumentValue("url", String.valueOf(map.get("liquibase.command.url")))
                    .addArgumentValue("username", String.valueOf(map.get("liquibase.command.username")))
                    .addArgumentValue("password", String.valueOf(map.get("liquibase.command.password")))
                    .addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.CHANGELOG_FILE_ARG, LIQUIBASE_CHANGELOG_FILE)
                    .addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.CONTEXTS_ARG, String.valueOf(map.get("contexts")));

updateCommand.execute();

I have the following error on updateCommand.execute()
liquibase.servicelocator.null Cannot load service
 java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParser: com.datical.liquibase.ext.parser.ProFormattedSqlChangeLogParser Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:672)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1232)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at liquibase.servicelocator.StandardServiceLocator.findInstances(StandardServiceLocator.java:22)
    at liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory.<init>(ChangeLogParserFactory.java:39)
    at liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory.getInstance(ChangeLogParserFactory.java:25)
    at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.getDatabaseChangeLog(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:124)
    at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.run(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:87)
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:219)

It seems like there is a no-arg constructor missing in the class liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParser.
Is there a missing dependency or configuration that I can add to fix this error?

Seems liquibase-core is bringing liquibase-commercial too. Could you try to exclude it?
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.27.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-commercial</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
 </dependency>


I tried with the exclusion but the errors are still there.... Thank you anyway!

If you use any other liquibase extension you need to add the same exclusion to it. Anyway it will be fixed on 4.28.0 release ,

Can you share the full error trace? In my case I was using opencsv 4.5 with liquibase-core 4.27.0. These were not compatible. On upgrading opencsv from 4.5 to 5.0 the error got fixed. Kindly check other dependencies in your pom.xml or build.grad

The error trace in my question was all i got. Anyway, I no longer have this error after upgrading to liquibase-core 4.29.0. Thank you for your answer!
Just being curious :) Did you have an error message to indicate the non compatibility of opencsv and liquibase-core? How could you find it?

Search opencsv in log you will find error
